# How to fix session id issue where 'request.getSession().getId()' is returning 'session id of 32 characters + (.test)'

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am getting below session id from `session.getId()`. I want to find out the source where I can correct and remove additional text with session id.

62E4CAF17CD801A3A8E8BB8802610FF1.test

```
From HttpServletRequest request

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String sessionId=session.getId();
System.out.println(sessionId);
```

Expected Result: 62E4CAF17CD801A3A8E8BB8802610FF1 from `session.getId()`

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you get from `request.getSession().getId()` *is* the correct session id. There's nothing to correct. You should handle it as atomic, random, unique stuff and not imply any meaning to it.

You can't assume that the id will stay 32 characters long: It might be 64 random characters in the next minor upgrade, or it might use a different alphabet, not just hexadecimal numbers. It might be followed by more than ".test".

E.g. I can't think of a valid business case for this requirement.

That being said, the jvmRoute, commonly configured in server.xml's `<Engine>` element, is typically being appended to the session id. It's required if you're running a load balancer with sticky sessions - if you remove it: Good luck with its operation. And if you don't use a loadbalancer today: You might tomorrow.

Be nice to your future self (or anybody else maintaining the app in question) and don't mock around with the session id.